# Angular2 empty response handling

Tags: angular

In my current application I can't seem to get a response from the observable when it's an empty array or when it takes too long for the server to reply. Here is my current state:

```
getIncomingData():Observable<any[]> {
    console.log("GetIncomingData");
    return this.http.get('http://mylink/data')
        .map(data => this.extractIncomingData(data))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractIncomingData(res:Response):any[] {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad respons status: ' + res.status);
    }
    console.log(res.json());
    return <any>res.json();
}
```

I have tried using the `.timeout` I found somewhere else but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm using Angular2 rc1. Does anyone know how to solve my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following if statement to extract data safely.

```
 if (res) {
       return res.json() || {};
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

nacho_dh's answer was close but `res` is an object that is unlikely to be null. In the case I had this issue the res object was a valid object but the `_body` property was '', this is what causes res.json() to throw an exception. So you need:

```
.map(res => (<any>res)._body == '' ? {} : res.json())
```

Note, given your working with Angular 2 and therefore Typescript you'll need to cast res to `<any>` because _body is private and Typescript won't let you access it.

yes I know its hacky, thanks